$E[X|Y]$ distribution.
In general, with random variables we are only interested in their distribution, and we consider those with the same distribution to be equivalent. Their properties generally depend only on their distribution. Thus, if $(X,Y)$ and $(X',Y')$ had the same distribution, one would expect that $E[X|Y]$ and $E[X'|Y']$ would coincide, but they do not. Should we perhaps modify the definition of conditional expectation so that this does not happen? What must necessarily be true is that $E[X|Y]$ and $E[X'|Y']$ have the same distribution. Is that so?

Can you give an example when they do not?

Elementary: $X$ and $X'$ different with the same distribution: $X=E[X|X]\neq E[X'|X']=X'$

Then the answer is even simpler: if $X$ and $X'$ have the same distribution, shouldn't $X$ and $X'$ coincide? (rhetorical question, of course). The reason is that having the same distribution is NOT the same as beeing identical!
